# How to plot 2 values in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have this set of dataframe: PLease refer to the link

I can plot the dividends vs years with:
df.plot(x='Year', y='Dividends', kind='line')

The question is how should I plot a line graph that shows Dividends+Interest and trade income against years?

[image: set of dataframe]

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).